# Images loading over http instead of https

Tags: ajax, ssl, https

I am new to wordpress and recently launched my blog on self-hosted version of wordpress. Everything is working fine except some images are loading over http resulting in insecure contents warning by the browsers. Here is the link of my page:- https://yumtoyikes.com

The issue is coming on single post page. When you Scroll down the post and at the bottom of page click on LOAD MORE button, the images loaded in result are being served on http instead of https.

Comment: Could you post the code for your `dw-loadmore-stream-list` function please?